# Windows Push Notification Services Token request via ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, push-notification, wns

I am trying to get the "access token" from WNS via a ColdFusion request but I get a "Bad Request" response. I believe I have everything set up correctly following the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187203.aspx). My devices are registering the URI's to my backend.

Here is a simple code snippet;
(I've hidden the secret key of course)

```
<cfhttp url="https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf" method="post" result="httpResp">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />

<cfhttpparam type="URL" name="grant_type" value="client_credentials" />
<cfhttpparam type="URL" name="client_id" value="ms%2Dapp%3A%2F%2Fs%2D1%2D15%2D2%2D1197233413%2D3602308102%2D1084427847%2D2188608249%2D1036687727%2D3580410356%2D2392468796" />
<cfhttpparam type="URL" name="client_secret" value="************************" />
<cfhttpparam type="URL" name="scope" value="notify.windows.com" />
```

I am also getting failed response when I test the URL directly [via the browser](https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ms-app%3A%2F%2Fs-1-15-2-1197233413-3602308102-1084427847-2188608249-1036687727-3580410356-2392468796&client_secret=**************************&scope=s.notify.live.net). Appreciate your help.

Thank you,

Ian.

Answer (score 0):

I think your cfhttpparam fields now set to "URL" should actually be set to "FORMFIELD" based on the example on MSDN.

```
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="grant_type" value="client_credentials" />
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="client_id" value="..." />
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="client_secret" value="************************" />
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="scope" value="notify.windows.com" />
```

The example appears to put thes in the content area (showing a raw post) - so these are form fields of a post, not URL fields right?

Comment: Cheers Mark for answer. Tried it but unfortunately it didn't work for me.
I would've thought they were URL params seeming as the URL itself should work (but does not either). Darn it anyway. Surprised this hasn't been asked before.